# How to add a driver by python for a custom property?

Tags: python, drivers

I just want to link a custom property from the texture data to a mapping node Scale input in the material but I can't get how to do it from examples

````
material_basic = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "Basic")
material_basic.use_nodes = True

mapping_node = material_basic.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMapping')

texture_data = bpy.data.textures.new("test_TX_DATA", "IMAGE")
texture_data["Map"] = 60 # my custom property
texture_data.driver_add('["Map"]')
```
````

Comment: I wrote a mockup code to show the problem.  I already have custom properties in material and texture data and I only need to know how to link these properties with nodes in materials. The same is what I could do with UI by "Add Driver" - "Paste Driver" but with python.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figure out what I did wrong. The main problem was I added a driver to the custom property instead of the node input

```
material_basic = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "Basic")
material_basic.use_nodes = True

mapping_node = material_basic.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMapping')

texture_data = bpy.data.textures.new("test_TX_DATA", "IMAGE")
texture_data["Map"] = 60 # my custom property

d = mapping_node.inputs[3].driver_add("default_value", 0) # add a driver to Scale X input
var1 = d.driver.variables.new() # add a driver variable
var1.name = "detail_multiplier" # add a name to this variable
var1.targets[0].id_type = 'TEXTURE' # set ID type to a target object with the custom attribute
var1.targets[0].id = texture_data # set the object as ID
var1.targets[0].data_path = '["Map"]' # link the custom property
d.driver.expression = var1.name # set the variable with the custom attribute value as an expression
```

[image: how it looks like in the driver editor]